# Downloading large external file in PHP - without error/timeout

Tags: php, timeout, runtime-error, file-get-contents

I'm incredibly frustrated as I can't seem to get past this error, no matter how I try.

My website requires I download a large (zipped) XML product feed - daily. The file size is variable; I get PHP warnings when the product feed is larger. There MUST be a way to resolve this!

The script downloads the file (still zipped) to my server:

```
<?php
file_put_contents('datafeed.xml.gz', file_get_contents('http://external website.com/format/xml/compression/gzip/'));
```

> Error: PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(...): failed to open stream:
>   HTTP request failed!  in... etc.

How do I solve this? Much appreciated!

Comment: as the error states, the http request FAILED. You need to figure out why. Have you tried downloading that file using other means? wget at the command line of the server? curl? ANYTHING other than f_g_c() which provides utterly useless diagnostic messages.

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: The error doesn't seem to be related to filesize or something. But if it comes to script timeouts, do you have access to php.ini? then you could raise the time limit for script execution.

Comment: Can you point me to some examples of this type of script in wget or cUrl @Marc B

Comment: If the zipped file contains less lines - I don't get this error; however if it goes above a certain number, I will always get it - which is I need a resolution because it varies @MarkusKottländer